# Is it possible to use a WHERE clause with Grass v.in.ogr for DGN sources?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, filter

I am trying to import a .DGN with Grass v.in.ogr in QGIS.  I am able to import the DGN perfectly, but I would like to filter the elements using the WHERE option.  From searching, reading and testing I think it should be running correct, but it is erroring out.  Any help would be appreciated.  The attribute column holding the information I would like to Filter on is called Level and it is an Integer. I want to filter it on a value of 1 (see attached image).[image: v.in.ogr filer]

Comment: I haven't used this tool, but maybe try putting Level in quotes: 'Level' = 1 or possibly "Level" = 1 or even putting the 1 in single quotes.

Comment: Level = 1 as in your screenshot works for me(qgis 1.8)

Comment: I have tried the "" and ''.  I am using 1.8.0 for Windows.  Vinaya, what data format are you importing?  Have you tried it with a .DGN.  I am concerned that the you can not filter based on an Autocad format.

Comment: i tried with a .dgn file

Comment: are you getting "￼Unable to open data source..Finished with error" in the output window?

Comment: "but it is erroring out" ... please tell us the error message.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies.  I am using a DGN version 7, on a Windows 7 machine with QGIS 1.8.0.  Here is the error message:
    v.in.ogr dsn=D:/Projects/QatarPetroleum3D/Testing/Vectors/LosAngeles_v7.dgn snap=-1 min_area=0.0001 "where=Level = 1" -o

￼Required parameter not set
Finished with error

Answer (score 1):

ogr cannot read Microstation DGN files if the versions starting from **8.0**. You could be using a newer version dgn file.

from the [gdal ogr website](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_dgn.html),

> **Microstation DGN**
>
> Microstation DGN files from Microstation versions predating version
>   8.0 are supported for reading. The entire file is represented as one layer (named "elements").